# Run a script automatically after logging into redhat

Tags: linux, redhat

Guys please I want to know how to start a script saying `hello root` after logging in automatically 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Add `echo "hello root"` to `/root/.bash_profile`?

Comment: After editing the bash profile how to save it ??

Answer (score 0):

Login as root, and if you're using bash, edit the `~/.bashrc` file to include the line `echo "hello root"` at the end of the file.

Comment: Inside `.bashrc` each time a terminal gets opened the script will be started.

Comment: The question was ambiguous if they were using the shell to login as root, and typically it's safe to assume that one isn't logging into the GUI as root. I would argue that my answer is just as relevant as yours.

Comment: Even if you are logging in as root you shouldn't use .bashrc for that target.

Answer (score 0):

Just put your script inside `~/.bash_profile` and it'll be launched after that user logs in.
Check out `man bash`.

Comment: How can I put it .. I am beginner to Linux

Comment: This opens the bash-profile ... Then what is the next step to put the script inside it ?

Comment: You should take a look at `man nano` as well. It's intuitive, though.